# Display single record from app to home page of the website in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display record on the website home from the app. In the admin interface records are getting displayed but on the website home its not working.

Site Structure

```
Site structure
website
--MyWebsite
----templates
--alert
----templates
```

Code at alert/view.py

```py
def weather_single(request):
    weatheronly=Weatherreport.objects.last()
    return render(request, '../MyWebsite/templates/sidebar_left.html', {'weatheronly':weatheronly})
```

Code at MyWebsite/templates/sidebar_left.html

```py
{% for wresult in weatheronly %}
{{ wresult.temp }}
{{ wresult.forecast }}
{% endfor %}
```

Code of url pattern
urlpatterns=[url('', views.weather_single, name='weather_single'),]

```
Currently not getting any error message and no results at all.
```

Comment: `.last()` returns you single object why are you iterating ?

Comment: Was about write what @PankajSharma wrote. `.last()` does not return a queryset but a single record. Remove the `for` and replace `wresult` with `weatheronly`.
Some light reading: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#last)

Comment: What is your URL pattern? Is it pointing at `weather_single`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a result in

`weatheronly=Weatherreport.objects.last()`

Best way to solve the problem is to assume your assumptions are incorrect and inspect if there is any data in the original pull.